# How to declare a dictionary with dynamic keys TypeScript Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, dictionary, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to declare a dictionary in TypeScript with dynamic key. I am quite new to TypeScript, this is what I tried:

I have a cloud function that gets an id from the path

```
const messageId = context.params.messageId; // -dbaASfcaer

// Compiles but the key value is 'childId'
const payload = {
    messageId : 1
}

const promise = ref.update(payload)
```

Also tried this but does not compile:

```
// Does not compile
const anotherPayload = {
    `${messageId}` : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you would need dynamic object keys like:

```
const anotherPayload = {
    [messageId] : 1
}
```